# Is it possible to use Active directory authentication through robot Framework?

Tags: automation, active-directory, robotframework

I am trying to automate test cases that uses active directory (LDAP) to log in. I have been searching on the internet and all I can see is people are asking about it, but there is no solution about it.
I am still a newbie, so the simplest way to learn something about it would be a big help.

Comment: Please share the automation tools that you are trying to use and some working example so that people can help you. Are you looking for something like this (https://automate.chef.io/docs/ldap/)?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. Let me try to explain it better: 
I have to automate several test cases using RIDE. It is a web application but the authentication is through windows active directory. My question is if is there a library to use on this kind of flow or if i will have to find another way to do it. 
As i said, i am still a newbie, so i also thought about creating a batch for every single user to do it (even tho i also dont know if it is possible) and run it using the "run" command for desktop files. 
I may be too far of reality here, so any help is welcome.

Comment: What's RIDE? Is it a programming language? You can put some working code and error (if any) so that similar experienced people can help you. And edit your question with details. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask